# Outlook ics/iCalender : ORGANIZER not reflecting in MacBook

Tags: macos, outlook, icalendar

I am using icalender spec for generating meeting invites in my application.The files is generated as below. The issue that i am facing is

**Problem:**

ORGANIZER is reflecting in the invite when i open the .ics file in Outlook on windows but not on Mac.

The ORGANIZER is according to the rfc. Line No :10

Please suggest if i am missing anything.

**ICS file**

1. BEGIN:VCALENDAR
2. PRODID:MyProdId
3. VERSION:2.0
4. CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
5. BEGIN:VEVENT
6. DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20180108T000000
7. DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20180108T130000
8. DTSTAMP;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20180102T223906
9. CREATED;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20180102T223906
10. ORGANIZER;CN=ABC XYZ:mailto:abc.xyz@company.com
11. CLASS:PUBLIC
12. DESCRIPTION:test
13. SUMMARY:My Summary
14. TRANSP:OPAQUE
15. BEGIN:VALARM TRIGGER:-PT60M
16. ACTION:DISPLAY
17. END:VALARM
18. LOCATION:MyLocation
19. UID:f5a89297db5b8b003d7958a8dc9619a2
20. SEQUENCE:0
21. END:VEVENT
22. END:VCALENDAR

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your event is not a true meeting invitation in that it does not have any ATTENDEE property.
As a consequence, the MacOS Client may just be ignoring the ORGANIZER property.

This is particularly true if abc.xyz@company.com also happens to be the email address associated with this calendar account.

Comment: Hi arnaudq,
Thanks for your response. I tried adding the the ATTENDEE property , but the behaviour still remains same.